# How to open app from other app within app in iOS

Tags: move

How to move from one app to another app in iOS.
How to go from one to another app if app exist in device at that moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "NameOfTheAppAsOnAppStrore:")
 // canOpenURL will return a bool value checking the presence of app in your device and if app is present, it will open the same.
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!)
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```